# Restore database to SQL server 2008 from SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I need to restore my database to SQL server 2008. Currently we are having our database in SQL Server 2005 in one server. We need to take the back up of that database and move that database to SQL server 2008 in another server. I can find the steps to move 2008 to 2008 or 2008 to 2005. But I can't find any documents or guidelines to move 2005 to 2008.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

From your question, it seems like you want to restore a SQL 2005 Database on a SQL 2008 Server. all you should have to do is backup the Database on SQL 2005, move the backup file, and restore on SQL 2008. However It is not supported to restore from SQL 2008 in SQL 2005

Answer (score 0):

It is not different to restoring 2008 DB to SQL Server 2008.

Fresh tutorial for you )))

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2011/restoring-sql-server-database-low-disk-space/